# No wifi after update to Kernel 4.10 / 4.11 - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, kernel, updates

My wifi is no longer working under kernel 4.10 / 4.11. Here is the output from `dmesg | grep iwl` under kernel 4.11

```
[    2.307045] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.307049] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

And here is the output from kernel 4.4 - with wifi functioning

```
[    1.786652] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.796735] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    1.901462] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[    1.901553] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    1.901848] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.120085] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.125075] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan1: renamed from wlan0
[    2.952782] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.953034] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.157418] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.157678] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.760611] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan1: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[    3.760615] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlan1: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
```

Any suggestions how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the missing firmware with

```
cd /lib/firmware
```

```
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
```

Then reboot into kernel 4.10

The iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode file is not in the linux-firmware package for 14.04